# Triple integral of perlin/simplex noises

Tags: math, 3d, noise, integral, cg

I'm wondering if it were possible to get the triple integral of a 3d noise function (for example perlin or simplex noises). I searched a little over the web but i haven't found any result.. if it were possible, we could calculate the sum of all f(x,y,z) (light/density/color/etc) in a given direction, given a start position (maybe even with infinite rendering distance). It could be cool.

I tried to manage the perlin noise algorithm and I found the integral of lerp(int(u), int(u)+1, t)
But I can't figure out how to integrate hash function or f(lerp).. any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Fun sounding question.  You may get some further help from Math Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try here too